# CasperJS querySelectorAll + map.call

Tags: javascript, casperjs, selectors-api

html file

```html
<table id="tbl_proxy_list">
...........
 <tr>
   ......
    <td align="left">
        <time class="icon icon-check">1 min</time>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        <div class="progress-bar" data-value="75" title="4625"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

ip.js file

```js
casper.start('http://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/', function() {
    var info_text = this.evaluate(function() {
        var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('table[id="tbl_proxy_list"] tr');
        return [].map.call(nodes, function(node) { 
            //return node.innerText;
            return node;
        });
    });

    var tr_data = info_text.map(function(str) {
        var elements = str;
        var data = {
            ip        : elements,
            port      : elements[1],
            lastcheck : elements[2],
            speed     : elements[3], // <== value is 75..
        };
        return data;
    });

    utils.dump(tr_data);
});

casper.run();
```

`return node.innerText` is only text.

- `ip` is a text value
- `port` is a text value
- `lastcheck` is a text value
- `speed` is **not** a text value (`data-value="75"`)

I want to import `data-value="75"` (speed value is 75).

I do not know what to do.

========================================

It's work.. good. thank you Artjom.

but tr_data echo error.

first, you code modify..

```
return {
    "ip":        tr.children[0].innerText.trim(),
    "port":      tr.children[1].innerText.trim(),
    "lastcheck": tr.children[2].innerText.trim(),
    "speed":     tr.children[3].children[0].getAttribute("data-value")
};
```

and echo..

```
//this.echo(tr_data.length);
for(var ii=0; ii<tr_data.length; ii++)
{
    this.echo(tr_data[ii]['ip']);
}
```

at run, blow error..

TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'tr_data.length'); what is problem?

I need your help.. thanks.

Comment: It's work.. thanks Artjom. but other problem :(

Comment: Ok, I see it is a problem with the ads.

Comment: you changed querySelectorAll('table[id="tbl_proxy_list"] tbody tr') ?? I chanage querySelectorAll, but still an error..

Comment: Now it's fixed. The ads were the problem. The code is changed too.

Comment: excellent!! Perfect code.. thank you very much Artjom B.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot pass DOM elements from the page context (inside `evaluate` callback).

From the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.

Returning an array of DOM elements will result in an array of as many `undefined` values. That means you need to map everything inside the page context and then return the resulting array. You also need only one `map`.

```
var tr_data = this.evaluate(function() {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('table[id="tbl_proxy_list"] tbody tr');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(nodes, function(tr, i) { 
        if (tr.children.length != 6) {
            return null; // skip ads
        }
        return {
            ip:        tr.children[0].innerText.trim(),
            port:      tr.children[1].innerText.trim(),
            lastcheck: tr.children[2].innerText.trim(),
            speed:     tr.children[3].children[0].getAttribute("data-value")
        };
    }).filter(function(data){
        return data !== null; // filter the null out
    });;
});
```

You also might want to `trim` the excess white space.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem and I post it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255267/casperjs-failed-to-execute-evalutate). Could you please give me some advices?