# CasperJS: execute evaluate failed while the same code succeed in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

The code:

```
var array = casper.evaluate(function () {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#J_bought_main > div > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(3) > div > div');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(nodes, function extractOrder(x) {
        var textNode = x.querySelector('table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5) > div > p:nth-child(2)');
        var urlNode =  x.querySelector('table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(6) > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span > a');
        return {
            'text': textNode != null ? textNode.textContent : "",
            'url': urlNode != null ? urlNode['href'] : ""
        };
    });
});

casper.echo(array.length);
```

And when I execute, it always fail with `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'array.length')`.

It seems the array which evaluate return is `null`, but when I execute the same script in Chrome console, it gives the correct result:

[image]

(There are some Chinese characters but it doesn't matter)

So why the same code succeed in Chrome but failed in my CasperJS evaluate? And How write a correct one?

Any advice would be appreciated.

---

From the [doc](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate):

> The concept behind this method is probably the most difficult to
>   understand when discovering CasperJS. As a reminder, think of the
>   evaluate() method as a gate between the CasperJS environment and the
>   one of the page you have opened; everytime you pass a closure to
>   evaluate(), you’re entering the page and execute code **as if you were
>   using the browser console**.

From the doc it claims if it succeed in Chrome console and it will succeed in my `evaluate` of CasperJS...

Comment: Looks fine to me. a) Have you taken a screenshot before to see if the many tables are actually there? b) Which PhantomJS version do you use? PhantomJS 1.x has a bug with `:nth-child`, but that likely wouldn't result in your observation. c) Can you show a larger portion of the code? d) Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Really thanks! I will check your advice and one by one...

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm faced with a new problem about `CasperJS`, could you please give me some advices? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758093/how-to-get-the-binary-of-the-image-requested-by-casperjs