# How to get the binary of the image requested by CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Code:

```
casper.on("resource.received", function (response) {
    if (response.url.indexOf('checkcode') != -1) {
        this.log('response: ' + JSON.stringify(response), 'debug');
    }
})
```

Output:

> [debug] [phantom] [2016-04-21T01:36:46.007Z] response:
>   {"body":"","bodySize":1847,"contentType":"image/png","headers":[{"name":"Server","value":"Tengine/2.1.0"},{"name":"Date","value":"Thu,
>   21 Apr 2016 01:36:45
>   GMT"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"image/png"},{"name":"Content-Length","value":"1847"},{"name":"Connection","value":"keep-alive"},{"name":"Strict-Transport-Security","value":"max-age=31536000"},{"name":"Cache-Control","value":"no-cache,
>   private,
>   must-revalidate"},{"name":"Pragma","value":"no-cache"},{"name":"Expires","value":"Fri,
>   01 Jan 1990 00:00:00
>   GMT"},{"name":"Set-Cookie","value":"JSESSIONID=48565DE1A6030B587CB9D14F9B53FBB4;
>   Path=/; HttpOnly\nJSESSIONID=48565DE1A6030B587CB9D14F9B53FBB4; Path=;
>   Secure;
>   HttpOnly\nspanner=Kkyr7NMMCJ+YBPeL1x6AIm/qefJ/jCic4EJoL7C0n0A=;path=/;secure;"}],"id":16,"redirectURL":null,"stage":"start","status":200,"statusText":"OK","time":"2016-04-21T01:36:46.007Z","url":"https://omeo.alipay.com/service/checkcode?sessionID=94e0a91bab9e202d3ee2e574e1c8f245&t=0.6211719120304562"}
>
> [debug] [phantom] [2016-04-21T01:36:46.011Z] response:
>   {"contentType":"image/png","headers":[{"name":"Server","value":"Tengine/2.1.0"},{"name":"Date","value":"Thu,
>   21 Apr 2016 01:36:45
>   GMT"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"image/png"},{"name":"Content-Length","value":"1847"},{"name":"Connection","value":"keep-alive"},{"name":"Strict-Transport-Security","value":"max-age=31536000"},{"name":"Cache-Control","value":"no-cache,
>   private,
>   must-revalidate"},{"name":"Pragma","value":"no-cache"},{"name":"Expires","value":"Fri,
>   01 Jan 1990 00:00:00
>   GMT"},{"name":"Set-Cookie","value":"JSESSIONID=48565DE1A6030B587CB9D14F9B53FBB4;
>   Path=/; HttpOnly\nJSESSIONID=48565DE1A6030B587CB9D14F9B53FBB4; Path=;
>   Secure;
>   HttpOnly\nspanner=Kkyr7NMMCJ+YBPeL1x6AIm/qefJ/jCic4EJoL7C0n0A=;path=/;secure;"}],"id":16,"redirectURL":null,"stage":"end","status":200,"statusText":"OK","time":"2016-04-21T01:36:46.010Z","url":"https://omeo.alipay.com/service/checkcode?sessionID=94e0a91bab9e202d3ee2e574e1c8f245&t=0.6211719120304562"}

And I got those logs, but there is no binary in the response, so I can't get the image...

So, how to get the binary of the image requested by CasperJS?

Comment: The response content is not available in PhantomJS. Since you have the URL, have you tried to `casper.download(...)` it?

Comment: @ArtjomB. The url returns different image for every request(a CAPTCHA indeed). So if I download it, it's not the CAPTCHA image displayed in the PhantomJS.

Comment: @ArtjomB. But I find a hack, `this.captureBase64('png', '#J-checkcode-img')`, that works...

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm got a new problem... I get the `Base64` code of that image, and I will send it to another HTTP server to parse that... So how to send a http request in `CasperJS`?

Comment: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#sendajax

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks your reply! But could I use a HTTP client like `superagent` to handle request out of the browser? It's very tricky(for me) to handle ajax cross origin request...

Comment: Just run the script with the `--web-security=false` commandline option and CORS will be disabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109860/discussion-between-sayakiss-and-artjom-b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ArtjomB commented:

> The response content is not available in PhantomJS

So I hack it by `this.captureBase64('png', '#J-checkcode-img')`.